# Estou com problemas para redimensionar uma imagem no React

Tags: javascript, css, react, imagem, front-end

Olá, sou estudante e estou com um problema em um projeto de front-end para redimensionar imagens usando CSS no React, as imagens vem da API publica do Mercado Livre, e por isso acabam chegando com tamanhos diferenciados, gostaria de colocar elas em um card, mas ao tentar usar o CSS eu me deparei com uma imagem que não redimensiona com nada do que escrevo.
Alguém pode me ajudar a encaixar essa imagem? o card vai ter `width: 250px; height: 400px;`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class CartProductCard extends Component {
state = {
  thumbnail: "http://http2.mlstatic.com/D_908098-MLB48245250077_112021-O.jpg"
  title: "PRODUTO"
}

render() {
const { thumbnail, title } = this.state
return (
<div className="image-container">
  <img
    className="=cart-image"
    src={ thumbnail }
    alt={ title }
  />
</div>
)}
}
```

```css
.cart-image img {
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
}

/* Já tentei usar max-width/height (mesmo não sendo a melhor opção para mim) */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: pergunta editada

Answer (score 0):

Apenas com o height e o width não será suficiente para que as imagens sejam redimensionadas independente do tamanho delas. Tente as propriedades abaixo. Vc pode pesquisar outras propriedades de background mas acredito que essas sejam suficientes.

.cart-image img {
width: 250px;
height: 100%;
background: url('url da imagem') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Opa Matheus, obrigado pela sugestão, mas o problema é que a imagem vem de uma API de forma dinâmica, então não tenho como passar essa info pra o css, ou pelo menos desconheço alguma forma de fazer isso. então não sei como usaria a funcionalidade de `background: url('url-da-imagem')`

Comment: Na vdd esse background ai foi apenas um exemplo. Voce pode utilizar da forma que está utilizando passando a url na tag img mesmo.  Já conseguiu achar a solução?